# loading django columns dynamically from another table

Tags: django

Using django, I want to define several columns in my Xon model based on the unique values stored in MyTypes.
This way, I do not need to manually define type1, type2, type3,...
and I can use the admin page to dynamically add a new type column.
Can someone explain how I can do that?

```
class Xon(models.Model):
    ge = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mu = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    des = models.TextField()
    type1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MyTypes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out abstract base classes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

From the docs:

> Abstract base classes
>
> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common
>   information into a number of other models. You write your base class
>   and put abstract=True in the Meta class. This model will then not be
>   used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base
>   class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child
>   class. It is an error to have fields in the abstract base class with
>   the same name as those in the child (and Django will raise an
>   exception).

And an example, also from the docs:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(CommonInfo):
    home_group = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```